# check history of my blockchain.info wallet via api

Tags: python, blockchain, blockchain.info-api

i am using https://blockchain.info/q api 
For checking my balance i use this link : `https://blockchain.info/ru/q/getreceivedbyaddress/a37ab54a
i want to know senders adress  and or history of my wallet transactions via api . Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not using that API, it isn't. There's only a few address related lookups as seen [here](https://blockchain.info/q), and none of them return a list of senders/receivers. However, with the [complete API](https://blockchain.info/api/blockchain_api), you can get a list of transactions as json with the format `https://blockchain.info/rawaddr/$bitcoin_address`.